# AWS Amplify Duplicate Error: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info at setModule

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I set up a new amplify, added auth, and a post confirmation lambda function to move user data into DynamoDB. When I run NPM start, I get this error:

> Failed to construct transformer:  DuplicateError: Duplicated files or mocks. Please check the console for more info
> at setModule (C:\Users\cjfew\Desktop\Fresh\MyDemo\node_modules\jest-haste-map\build\index.js:543:17)
> .js:426:22 {

> mockPath1: 'amplify\#current-cloud-backend\function\FreshAuthPostConfirmation\src\package.json',

> mockPath2: 'amplify\backend\function\FreshAuthPostConfirmation\src\package.json'
> }
> '''

Based on what I have read, #current-cloud-backend gets created by amplify, based on the files in the backend folder. It seems like that package.json is supposed to be there, but I am not sure why it is an error. I saw somewhere that I should just delete the subclass duplicate file, which I assumed to be the one in #current-cloud-backend, but amplify is going to keep producing this error every time I push to it, how do I avoid this from happening at all?